# What is the significance of the the leading "4" before the listing of modified files?

Tags: shell, find, disk-usage

After running the following command:

```
find /Users/UserName/Documents -type f -mtime -1 -print0 | xargs -0 du -sk | sort -nr
```

I receive the following output:

```
4   /Users/UserName/Documents/SubFolder/hello_2.txt
4   /Users/UserName/Documents/SubFolder/hello.txt
4   /Users/UserName/Documents/hello.txt
```

What is the significance of the leading "4 "?

Comment: Why `sudo`, why?

Comment: It is the **d**isk **u**sage of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You told **du** to output sizes in k, so the file is most likely smaller than 4K, but occupies that much space on disk.